# SQL Server Full-Text search - get total field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains

Let's say I have the following table "`Addresses`":

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------------+
| ID | CompanyName |    Street     |     City         |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------------+
|  1 | Salvador    | Hollywood 123 | Paradise City    |
|  2 | Zer0        | Avenue 34     | Opportunity City |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------------+
```

If I make a full-text search like:

```
SELECT * FROM Addresses WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'Salv')
```

Is it possible to get back

- the name of the column, which contains the founded value (in this example it would be "CompanyName")
- the full value of the column, which contains the founded value (in this example it would be "Salvador"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get column name of particular value in sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941707/how-to-get-column-name-of-particular-value-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest this:

```
 SELECT 
      *,
      CASE WHEN CONTAINS(CompanyName, 'Salv') THEN 'CompanyName'
           WHEN CONTAINS(Street, 'Salv') THEN 'Street'
           WHEN CONTAINS(City, 'Salv') THEN 'City'
      END As ColumnName,
      CASE WHEN CONTAINS(CompanyName, 'Salv') THEN CompanyName
           WHEN CONTAINS(Street, 'Salv') THEN Street
           WHEN CONTAINS(City, 'Salv') THEN City
      END As FullText
 FROM Addresses 
 WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'Salv')
```

Comment: thx for your answer! I know i can do it in that (or a similar) way, but i thought that maybe there would be an easier approach.

Comment: I have to search very generic, so if i would go with the above approach, i would have to look for each table which columns are full-text-searchable an then i could create the correct statement. If there is no other solution, i'll try that.